# How to generate random numbers from the given numbers

Tags: javascript, random, numbers

I have an scenario to generate random numbers that should generate from the given numbers.

for example, I have an array num=[23,56,12,22]. so i have to get random number from the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

let num=[23,56,12,22];
let randomPosition = getRandomInt(num.length);
console.log(num[randomPosition])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function that returns a random integer between 0 and the length of the array, like this:

```
function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}
```

Then call it, like this:

```
let randomInt = getRandonInt(lengthOfArray);

console.log(randomInt);
```

Expected output: 0, 1, 2 .. length of array

Then just simply use the randomInt to get whatever you need from your array entries.

Answer (score 1):

you can generate a random index between `0` and `array.length - 1`

```js
function getRandomInt(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

function getRandomIntFromArray(array) {
    return array[getRandomInt(array.length)]
}

const num = [23,56,12,22]

getRandomIntFromArray(num)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Math.floor(Math.random() * x)`, where x is the length of the Array to generate a random number between 0 and the max index

```js
const data = [23,56,12,22]

function randomIndex (array) {
  return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
}

console.log(randomIndex(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about drawing a uniform distributed random integer in the interval `[0,len(num)-1]` which represents the index of the number you draw from your array `num`.

This is a very simple and straight forward approach.